# Adding movement to 3D text

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Attempting to make text move with the left and right arrows.
I placed a 3D text component and added a c# script for movement.
I attached the script to the text but it doesn't want to move.

Whats the trick? It works when using a cube but thats not what i'm trying to do.

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0)
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0,0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out but had to add a box collider and set it correctly